# OHLC prices after filtering

Tags: stochastic-processes, market-data, pricing, tick-data, ohlc

Assume we have minute-bars of OHLC stock prices. Then, applying Kalman filter to those prices separately, we can remove a measurement noise and obtain the estimates of the states of the price processes.

The observations is: after Kalman filtering, some high prices become smaller than low prices. Can it cause some problems?

In my opinion, it is not a problem. In a feature creation after filtering, it it happens that $High < Low$ then I would just flip them.

Comment: You haven't explained the purpose of the Kalman filter.

Comment: It is more common to use the closing price.  This will avoid the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I would like to use all prices in the bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about preprocessing the data and create mid_price = (H+L)/2 and range = H-L. And your Kalman filter apply to mid_price and range. Then you will not have the problem as you described